# What is the minimal number of partial orders whose union equals a given binary relation on a finite set?

Tags: order-theory

I'm reading Bertrand Russell's 1901 *On The Notion of Order*. My question **isn't from** the book *per se*, but I say that for whatever context it provides. Probably none. Anyway, here is the question:

Let $S$ be a finite set. Suppose we have a binary relation $R \subseteq S \times S$, where $S$ is some set. Is there a smallest number $k$ of partial orders $P_1, \cdots, P_k$ such that any such relation $R$ satisfies $R = \cup_{i=1}^k P_i$? We'll take each $P_i \subseteq S_i \times S_i$, and that $\cup_i S_i = S$. Distinct $S_i$ need not be disjoint.

My first thought for dealing with any violations of antisymmetry is that $k \geq 2$ for arbitrary $R$ to get $(a,b) \in P_1$ and $(b,a) \in P_2$ when $a \neq b$.

Comment: An  aggressive try is to make a linear order on $S$, then make two total orders, one generated by the linear order and one generated by the reverse.  Every pair in $S \times S$ that does not have matching elements is in one or the other.  This doesn't work because the relation may not be transitive, but it is a place to start thinking.

Comment: There is a trivial answer to that which is no. For if $R$ is not reflexive, and $s\in S$ is such that $(s,s)\notin R$, then whatever may be $P_1, \ldots P_k$ in such a way that $P_i$ is an order relation on $S_i$ and $\bigcup_i S_i=S$, then $s\in S_{i_0}$, for some $i_0$, whence $(s,s)\in P_{i_0}$, and therefore, $R\nsubseteq \bigcup_i P_i$.

Comment: Now you might have something else in mind. For example, for $R reflexive; there might be the need for other constrains, in order for the question to be more meaningful. I can't say...